# Running webdriver tests in Opera

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver, opera

I'm trying to run the tests on opera using webdriver 2.3. Although the browser opens the tests are not getting executed.

Browser just opens the profile dir as shown in the screenshot.

Am I missing anything?

[image]

Comment: Care to share what code you are using?

Comment: Here is the code  
case OPERA: proxy.setProxyAutoconfigUrl(commandArgs.get("proxyURL").toString()); dc = DesiredCapabilities.opera(); dc.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy); driverPojoObj.setDriver(new OperaDriver(dc)); break;

Comment: @Anil: if you've got extra information, it's best to edit your question to include it. It's more readable, and it also means that any new reader can easily see the whole question in one go without scanning through the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following process:

- Find a testrunner based on your language, such as:

  - [grunt-webdriver](https://github.com/webdriverio/grunt-webdriver)
  - [gulp-webdriver](https://github.com/webdriverio/gulp-webdriver)
  - [watir-webdriver](https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver)
  - [php-webdriver-for-phpunit](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver)
  - [webdriver-for-Robot](https://github.com/rickypc/robotframework-extendedselenium2library)
  - [webdriver-for-nunit](http://relevantcodes.com/using-nunit-to-execute-selenium-webdriver-tests/)
  - [webdriver-for-mstest](http://bipinkarms.com/automated-ui-tests-with-selenium-and-mstest/)
  - [selenium-cucumber-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-cucumber-js)
  - [serenity-bdd](https://github.com/serenity-bdd)
- Add the path the to test file(s) to the testrunner
- Pick the [OperaPrestoDriver](https://github.com/operasoftware/operaprestodriver) or [OperaChromiumDriver](https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver)
- Add the path the the OperaDriver to the testrunner
- Start the Selenium server
- Start the testrunner